# R: How to extract value generated inside function

Tags: r

I want extract a value inside of a pre-defined function. For example:

```
sample <- function(x,y){
  p = rnorm(x,y)
  estim = mean(p)
  estim
}
```

Suppose this is a pre-defined function so I cannot change it after running it. Is it possible for me to also store/read the `p` generated when I am calling the function?

Comment: You'll need to [trace](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/trace.html) the function and have it return it (eg together with the normal return value in a list) or assign it to some environment.

Comment: As you have stated it, no.  On the basis of the comments below, it might make sense to describe your actual problem with a little more realism and context, someone might be able to help.